# Electric Sheep on Raspberry Pi

Tags: pi-2

I have recently installed [Electric Sheep](http://www.electricsheep.org/), an awesome program, on my Model 2 Pi, using [these](http://www.electricsheep.org/node/51) instructions. However, for those of you who know about Electric Sheep...It's not letting me vote on sheep. I've tried a new keyboard and restarting the Pi, among other things. Anybody know what to do?

Comment: In what way does it not let you vote? Can the Pi see the internet? Did you run the program as root? Is there anything in the logs? Can you run it from a command line?

Comment: @rob The program itself runs fine, and I tend to launch it from LXTerminal, but when I press the arrow keys, it doesn't count my vote, or at least doesn't pop up the sheep animation.

Comment: If you are running it from the command line I would have hoped for some output if there was a problem. Have you tried running as root via sudo? Apart from that I am at a loss.

Comment: @rob Okay...The command line(LXTerminal) outputs outputs about a hundred of these:
 "[avi @ 0xd9eda0] max_analyze_duration reached",
        
and then: 'please upgrade to the latest client from www.electricsheep.org', and then more of the above, repeat, repeat, repeat.

Comment: @rivermont-WillB. did you use the PPA or the "old way" on that page you mentioned?